# why there is no running process, but there is an error saying" cuda out of memory"?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qErO7.png)

In the code part, i set device='cuda'

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 0):

The process was killed because it raised a *Runtime* error because of your GPU device ran out of memory. And by the time you entered `nvidia-smi` in the console, the GPU memory was already cleared.